# Issue with IE detection via PHP

Tags: php, internet-explorer

I'm using the following code to show up different menu to IE users,

```
<?php 
    $IE6 = (ereg('MSIE 6',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) ? true : false;
    $IE7 = (ereg('MSIE 7',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) ? true : false;
    $IE8 = (ereg('MSIE 8',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) ? true : false;

if (($IE6 == 1) || ($IE7 == 1) || ($IE8 == 1)) { ?>
        //content for IE users
<?php }
else
{ ?>
    //content for users rather than IE
<?php }
?>
```

But sometimes when i go to the website with other browsers in either mac or windows the IE menu showed up to me, this is totally random and is not consistent.

What is wrong with this code?

Comment: `ereg` is depreciated, browser specific content is a poor approach

Comment: Search the net for a better approach. This does not work for IE11 and other browsers.

Comment: @Dagon I also used the `preg_match` but i got the same result, do you have better idea?

Comment: @user3132781 I just want to detect IE 7-8-9

Comment: This could be beacuse some older browsers have a wrong User-Agent and pretend they are MSIE (due to restrictations Microsoft had earlier) - at least I m so told.

Comment: @user3132781 i used the code twice in the page, Is that something that might be cause the issue?

Comment: I do not think so (the $_SERVER should be always present). But if you can test it on your system include an echo on $IE6,7,8.   For this purpose I have a logfile I fill with all important data.